# llenar automaticamente tablas intermedias mysql

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando llenar una tabla intermedia de manera automatica apartir de otra el ejemplo es el siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en donde al llenar la tabla ESPECIFICAMENTE el campo salario (#13)
se deberia llenar el mismo en la la siguiente tabla intermedia como registro unicamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probe la relacion de tabla 1 a tabla 2 con tipo cascada pero solo se guarda en la tabla 1.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder realizar lo que deseas hacer es necesario realizar un  `Trigger` de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_on_tabla2  
    --Indicas de donde proviene la acción a ejecutar en tu caso después de insertar en la tabla1.
    BEFORE INSERT ON tabla1
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
    --Se realiza la acción que se desea hacer.
    INSERT INTO tabla2 (salario) VALUES (NEW.salario); 
END
```